# How to print the numbers in alert box?

Tags: javascript

This code is showing the alert box when the two numbers entered are same,now I want show the numbers in the alert box it is showing only one number,but I want to show each number which is same for example,if I enter 83 in two input boxes and 85 in other two input boxes,the alert box should show 83 and 85,you can not enter these numbers more than once.
    function validateForm() {

```
    for (var x = 0; x < 81; x++) {
        for (var y = x + 1; y < 81; y++) {
            if (document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + x].value == document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + y].value) {
                if (document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + x].value == "") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('You can not enter a number more than once');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you ask for string concatenation, aka: `"The answer to the question about the universe, life, and the rest is: " + 42`?

Comment: No I want to show the numbers of the document.forms["myform"]['pk' +x] in the alert box.

Comment: To clarify, you want a single alert with a list of numbers that have been duplicated, e.g. "21, 23, 25 You can not enter a number more than once"

Comment: Exactly sir that what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completely different take on it, 81 iterations only, rather than 3000+

```
function validateForm() {
    var q = {}, a = [];
    for (var i=0; i<81; i++) {
        var value = document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+i].value;
        if (value !== "") {
            if (q[value]) {
                if (q[value] < 2) {
                    a.push(value);
                }
                q[value] ++;
            }
            else {
                q[value] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a.length) {
        alert(a.join(', ') + ' You can not enter a number more than once');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This loops through all the values a single time, keeping a tally of how many of each value there is (var q) - if a tally of a value hits 2, the value is added to the array (var a). So, triples, quadruples etc, will only be reported once.

If a.length > 0, the alert is shown and false is returned

Comment: Thanks Sir,that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `return` inside the loop, else declare a variable say `validate` and store true and false values in it and return it at the end, else the function execution will stop at return. Modified code is:

```
function validateForm() {
    var validate = true;
    for (var x = 0; x < 81; x++) {
        for (var y = x + 1; y < 81; y++) {
            if (document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + x].value == document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + y].value) {
                if (document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + x].value == "") {
                } else {
                    alert('You can not enter a number more than once. Duplicate number is:'+ document.forms["myForm"]['pk' + x].value);
                        validate =  false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return validate;
    }
```

Comment: That will alert once for every duplicated number, without showing the number that is duplicated

Comment: Yea you are right but the alert part can be easily changed by the OP easily, I told him the logic instead which was the main focus. Editing the answer though, thanks :)

Comment: but it shows only one duplicate number what if there are more than one duplicate numbers?

Comment: It would multiple duplicate elements, are you sure it is not working?

Answer (score -1):

From your code, this can help you

```
 <script>
            function validateForm() {

        var val1,val2;
            for (var x=0; x<81; x++) {
                for (var y=x+1; y<81; y++) {
        val1 = document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+x].value;
        val2 = document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+y].value
                  if (document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+x].value==document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+y].value) {

                   if ( document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+x].value=="") {
                   return true;
                   }
                   else {
                    alert(val1 + 'and'+ val2 +',You can not enter a number more than once');
                    return false;
                    }
                  }else{
                   alert(val1 + 'and'+ val2 +',You can not enter a number more than once');
                    return false;
}


                }


              }


              return true;
            }



            </script>
```

Comment: But it is only showing one number, if I enter two same numbers in the two boxes and two same numbers in the other boxes,it  only shows one number in the alert box for example 57 and 57 it should show those two same numbers 57 and 58 etc.

Comment: @Pardeep, I edited my answer.pls chk and let me know that it is worked for you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `val` and `val2` in the `if` statements?

Comment: @TripeHound, variables are  initialised before if else statement, so i think it is good thing(but programming is based on your logic).

Comment: @ Sumit Jha - that code alerts on first iteration where at least one value is not "".

Comment: No it does not work either the code alerts on first iteration,does not give the desire output,I want to show the same numbers in the alert box,for example there are four boxes and user enter 4 numbers 2,2,3,3 since two numbers are same these numbers should show in the alert box you can not enter more than once 2,3 etc.